# How to show Page Loading html file until the page has finished loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I need a different page loader file (like: `loader.html`) in which i have only `loader.gif` image with some css styling not in the same `index.html` file. So now i want to load my `index.html` file before it loads i want to show my `loader.html` file and if my all content loaded hide the `loader.html` file and show `index.html` file content.
Hope you understand what i am saying please help :)

I tried this Code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    if($("body").load("loader.html").fadeOut(5000)){
        $("loader.html").hide();
        $("index.html").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to load two different sets of html files. My suggestion would be load your index.html file and start showing the loader.gif and in the background wait for other resources to be loaded. Once that finished you can hide the loader.

Comment: @Ashok, What is `window.onload` invokes before `ajax` is completed...?

Comment: @Ashok Yes sir you are right but i want to try this in different way can you please help?

Comment: @RaviSah Doing it like you want (loading two distinct html files) is not a good idea at all. You will lose a bunch of time loading the first page and you'll then be forced to load the second one over an XMLHttpRequest and replace the first one (all with JavaScript), and this is unnecessary, unsafe and slow. I don't think any developer would give you advice on how to do this: is like asking a police officer how to rob a bank.

Comment: What is this what are you trying to hide show `$("loader.html").hide();$("index.html").show();` with this code? ;)

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I want it just for the knowledge that how to do it. Thanks!!

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 I have no knowledge of scripting language i am just trying it by reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .load( url [, data ] [, complete ] ) [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("body").load("loader.html", function(){
    /* place code need to executed after loader.html load */
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks i like this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. On Page Load show your `.gif` or loader`.html` in some `<div>` as you required.
2. Make ajax call to load html.
3. After complete ajax call hide/remove .`gif/loader.html` and show your `index.html`.

This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. try this instead
   On document.load function() show the loader .
   On document.ready function() hide the loader`

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //for demo, I used timer for 3 second
    var timer = window.setTimeout(requestPage, 3000);

    function requestPage(){
        sendRequest("index.php", function(sResponse){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            //clear everything everything in body HTML
            //change inner html with sResponse
            $("body").children().fadeOut(300, function(){
                $(this).remove();
                $("body").html(sResponse)
            });
        });
     }

    function sendRequest(url, oncomplete){
       $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'html',
         cache: false,
         timeout: 60000,
         complete: function(e, xhr, opt) {
            if(typeof oncomplete === "function") oncomplete(e.responseText);
          }
       });
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="loader"><img src="loader.gif" /> <em>Loading page. Please wait...</em></div>
```

Hope you can help